# How to evaluate the file bytes size and the disk's real usage?

Tags: file-io, diskspace

First, I throw the truth: When you write 1KB bytes to disk, the real disk usage is not
precisely 1KB, maybe more of that.

I'm downloading file from some third-party file system to
local disk. On each file downloading, I can get the file size from HTTP response, for
example, 7kb, and I added it the the disk's usage (a counter variable), when the usage reach 90% of the disk's
capacity, the program will switch to other available disk automatically. But when I do
the real job, the disk's real usage increase faster then the real received bytes, before
I download 2TB bytes (at 1TB, for example), the disk's usage has reached to 2TB (use
`df -h`), how to precisely evaluate the disk usage when downloading files? is there a
ratio between file byte size and the real disk usage?

Once I plan to use `df -h` to get the realtime disk usage, but on each file download creat
a OS process is not realistic.

Comment: Note that you can get the result of running `df -h` and parsing the result directly with the `statvfs` function.

Comment: @DanD. You deserve the 10 point.